# Using spring together with jbossws-cxf on jboss 6

Tags: spring, jboss6.x, jbossws

I want to use spring together with jbossws-cxf. Is this possible?

First I tried using jbossws-cxf.xml with bean definitions of spring. The warning message `[DescriptorDeploymentAspect] Spring not available, skipping check for user provided jbossws-cxf.xml / cxf.xml configuration files.` states that the file gets ignored and means that you should install spring in order for it to not get ignored :-) . [So I installed spring for jboss.](https://community.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13545).

After installation and running of a simple MathWS together with a simple WS example I get a

```
  [org.jboss.wsf.stack.cxf.client.configuration.JBossWSSpringBusFactory] INITIAL_APP_CONTEXT_CREATION_FAILED_MSG: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.customEditorConfigurer' defined in URL [vfs:/D:/lifeDevSuite/jboss/jboss-6.0.0.FinalSpring/common/lib/cxf-rt-bindings-soap.jar/META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.fixml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.ArrayList' to required type 'org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar[]' for property 'propertyEditorRegistrars'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.spring.SoapVersionRegistrar] to required type [org.springframework.beans.PropertyEditorRegistrar] for property 'propertyEditorRegistrars[0]': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
```

error.

My jbossws-cxf.xml looks like this: 
`

```
<beans
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
 http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">


<bean id="mathBean" class="com.sample.MathWS">
    <constructor-arg value="alabama" />
</bean>


<jaxws:endpoint id="MathWSX" implementor="#mathBean" address="http://localhost:8080/HelloCXF" />
```

`

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Sadly - I cannot recall how. And please forgive me - but I'm not going back to try and reproduce it :-)
Basically the answer is "yes". To that specific problem, it may have been a namespace problem, e.g. correct would be

```
<beans
 xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
 xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
 http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.5.xsd
 http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
 http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
```

It may have been as well that custom spring libraries were deployed (I think it is recommended using the spring libraries coming with jboss and are deployed dynamically automagically)

It may have been something else alltogether